# Add .com to end of my string in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

What I'm trying to is search my string to see if there is any of the following arrays there

if not then we need to add .com to end of it.

$kwlines is my string and i have set it to test but this is what I get

> test.comtest.com.comtest.com.com.comtest.com.com.com.comtest.com.com.com.com.comtest.com.com.com.com.com.comtest.com.com.com.com.com.com.com

```
foreach ($kwlines as $kw) {

$owned_urls= array('.com', '.co.uk', '.net','.org', '.gov','.gov.co.uk','.us');

foreach ($owned_urls as $url) {
if (strpos($kw, $url) !== TRUE) {
    $kw .= ".com";
    echo "$kw";
 }
 }
```

Could you please help me understand what I do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Your code is running for each TLD in that array. Pull it out of the array...

Comment: You could also try [preg_match](http://nl1.php.net/preg_match) with a regex: ((\.)(net|com|org|co.uk|gov|us|gov\.co\.uk))$ If it doesn't match, add .com to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach ($kwlines as $kw) {
   $owned_urls= array('.com', '.co.uk', '.net','.org', '.gov','.gov.co.uk','.us');

   foreach ($owned_urls as $url) {
      $find = 0;
      if (strpos($kw, $url) !== TRUE) {
         $find = 1;
      }
    }
    if($find == 1)
       $kw .= ".com";

    echo "$kw";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($owned_urls as $url) {
    if (strpos($kw, $url) !== TRUE) {
        $kw .= ".com";
        echo "$kw";
        exit();
     }
 }
```

Your code is running for each TLD in that array. Pull it out of the array...once the tld is found, it exists the foreach loop in my example above.

Comment: Still getting   test.com.com.com.com.com.com.com and so on